# Simple hello world for Android app won't display text

Tags: android

I recently bought an Android phone and am trying to learn to code my own apps. Unfortunately after the first ten seconds I ran into the problem where I can't even get the ["hello world" tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) to display "hello world."

I've read similar posts and I can't seem to find a fix. Since the Android loading logo is displaying I've waited for about ten minutes thinking it was just taking a while for the emulator to boot, but no luck.

```
package multivax.random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RandomNumbersActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello World");
        this.setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator or phone? What is the output of `adb logcat`?

Answer (score 0):

do not close the emulator once you have turned it on. just recompile it and send it to the already open emulator.

why are you saying `this.setContentView(tv);` instead of just `setContentView(tv);` ?

and by the way check you xml file to make sure that this is the main activity (i.e. the activity that starts when your application starts)

Answer (score 0):

this.setContentView(tv) is also equals setContentView(tv), there have no problem. also right Android code. You only can find something by adb logcat,you will find some usable information.